# Filter items in database by comparing more than one colunm?

Tags: android

I want filter items by KEY_PRODUCT_NAME and also KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY. How can i do this?

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
KEY_CODE, KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY},
KEY_PRODUCT_NAME+ " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `%` in your selection directly and also should use `AND` keyword to filter based on two or more conditions
change your code as follow:

```
mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
KEY_CODE, KEY_PRODUCT_NAME, KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY},
KEY_PRODUCT_NAME+ " like ? AND " + KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY + " LIKE = ?", new String[] { "%" + inputText + "%", "%"+ category + "%"} ,
null, null, null, null);
```

This is selection `KEY_PRODUCT_NAME+ " like ? AND " + KEY_PRODUCT_CATEGORY + " LIKE = ?"` and selectionArgs `new String[] { "%" + inputText + "%", "%"+ category + "%"}`